# Как конвертировать HTML-текст в обычный?

Tags: javascript, html

Есть такая строка:

`на уровне около &#036;300`

Как её конвертировать из хтмл вида в обычный текст вида?

`на уровне около $300`

Экшеном замена это не сделать, т к в тексте много других символов которые в хтмл закдированы

Answer (score 0):

Добрые люди написали функцию :)

```
var decodeHtmlEntity = function(str) { return str.replace(/&#(\d+);/g, function(match, dec) { return String.fromCharCode(dec); }); };
```

Попробуйте, достаточно ли этого для Ваших нужд

Взято отсюда https://gist.github.com/CatTail/4174511